# How to use FFMPEG for good/professional screen recording?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I did my own research and came up with this code:

```
 ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 24 -i desktop output.avi
```

So what can I do to improve the bitrate or the quality in general? Also, is it possible to pause/continue the recording? I know **q** but this stops the recording.

The quality is too bad as shown and I think it's due to low bitrate [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pause the recording by clicking on the command prompt, causing 'Select' to be appended to the title of the window. When you want to unpause, switch back to command line and hit any key to bring it back to focus and resume recording.

To fix the blocky encoding I modified your command to this:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -i desktop -b:v 1000k -b:a 20k output.mkv
```

It still has a rather low framerate, so you might look into GPU NVENC acceleration for FFmpeg. However, the better alternative would be [OBS](https://obsproject.com/), a software actually designed for screen recording

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Nice answer :-) However please take [the Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to learn how Q&A sites like these differ from internet message boards / forums. Please also see the Questions- and Answers -sections in the  [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how to make good ones. You can also look around to see what accepted answers look like. I re-formatted your answer now to fit better into this kind of site. You could've also added a photo of your output for proof - you're not allowed to embed images yet, but you can add links - we usually change them.

Comment: +1 for adding the OBS alternative :-)

Comment: Okay thanks for doing that sorry for the trouble!

Comment: No worries brother/sister/other, it's all part of the package :-) This time I did it during the answer review, but if you look around you'll see "Edited by" can appear at any posting at any point of time. It's all about sharing knowledge, and maintaining certain standard level is beneficial to all :-)